# Redshift - Doing incremental updates of data

Tags: sql, sql-update, amazon-redshift, sql-insert

I am trying to perform an incremental update of my datamart.

Given below is the current view of my datamart

```
sale_id,prod_name,created_date,updated_date,prod_category
1,prod_1,2018-07-05 10:00:00,2018-07-05 11:00:00,Type_A
2,prod_1,2018-07-05 12:00:00,2018-07-05 12:05:00,Type_A
3,prod_2,2018-07-05 14:20:00,2018-07-05 15:33:00,Type_B
4,prod_3,2018-07-05 18:50:00,2018-07-05 19:00:00,Type_C
```

Primary key is *sale_id* column and I need to perform update or insert based on *created_at* or *updated_at*.

Could anyone advice what would the best way to perform incremental updates. Currently I do a simple delete and then insert into the table to refresh the data every hour.

```
select s.sale_id,p.prod_name,s.created_date,s.updated_date,p.prod_category
from sales s join products p on s.prod_id=p.id and s.created_at >=CURRENT_DATE - 30;
```

I am trying to perform an hourly update which would be as below:

```
(created_date >= dateadd(hour, - 1 , getdate())) or (updated_date >= dateadd(hour, - 1, getdate()))
```

Could anyone assist, thanks..

Answer (score 0):

> Primary key is sale_id column and I need to perform update or insert based on created_at or updated_at.

You may be doing like, created_at=updated_at or updated_at is null means `create` else `update`. I think this is correct approach for finding incremental records(or changed records)

> Could anyone advice what would the best way to perform incremental updates. Currently I do a simple delete and then insert into the table to refresh the data every hour.

Your approach of DELETE and then INSERT is correct, as in Redshift

> UPDATE=DELETE + INSERT

Your are doing explicit DELETE and INSERT, hence this is good.

One thing though I would like to point here though not asked, make sure you do `VACUUM DELETE Only` most of time or frequently to get better performance after `delete/insert queries`.